# Nested nested relationships with Stash

Tags: stash, relationships, nested-list

I'm trying to display a nested nested list of relationship entries using stash. The following standard EE template code correctly displays all of the data.

```
{!-- Category page --}
{exp:channel:entries channel="category_page" entry_id="16609" dynamic="no"}

    {!-- Category page title --}
    {title}

    {!-- Get parent Landing page content --}
    {parents field="cf_landing_categories"}

        {!-- Parent Landing page Feature 1 Places title --}
        {parents:cf_landing_feature1_title}

        {!-- Parent Landing page Feature 1 Places --}
        {parents:cf_landing_feature1_places}
            {parents:cf_landing_feature1_places:title}
        {/parents:cf_landing_feature1_places}

    {/parents}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However, if I then try to put this into Stash nested code as follows, only the {feature_list1_title} displays;

{!-- SET LIST --}

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="category-{segment_2}" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" parse_depth="3" save="yes" refresh="60" scope="site" replace="yes"}

    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="category_page"
        disable="{global:channel_disable_basic}"
        status="open"
        limit="1"
        require_entry="yes"
    }

        {stash:category_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:category_entry_id}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="landing-{segment_1}-feature-list1" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

            {parents field="cf_landing_categories"}

                {!--Landing page places title--}
                {stash:feature_list1_title}{parents:cf_landing_feature1_title}{/stash:feature_list1_title}

                {!--Landing page places--}
                {exp:stash:set_list:places name="landing-{segment_1}-feature-list1-places" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

                    {parents:cf_landing_feature1_places}

                        {stash:feature1_place_title}{parents:cf_landing_feature1_places:title}{/stash:feature1_place_title}

                    {/parents:cf_landing_feature1_places}

                {/exp:stash:set_list:places}

            {/parents}

        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

{!-- GET LIST --}

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="category-{segment_2}"}

    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="landing-{segment_1}-feature-list1" context="{category_entry_id}" save="yes" scope="site"}

        {feature_list1_title}

            {exp:stash:get_list:places context="{category_entry_id}" name="landing-{segment_1}-feature-list1-places" orderby="random" limit="3"}

                {feature1_place_title}

            {/exp:stash:get_list:places}

    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_lists` are using `context` but your `set_lists` are not, so they won't match up (context is really just a prefix for the `name`).

Comment: Hey @James Smith, sorry for the late reply. I didn't receive a notification that someone had replied. I took off the context from the exp:stash:get_list:places as I don't think that was right anyway, but still don't get the nested relationship working. Or maybe it's that I'm not sure what the context needs to be for the exp:stash:set_list:places :/

Comment: did you also remove it from the outer get_list?

Comment: I left this one in place as this one seems to be working fine as it is correctly getting the {feature_list1_title} inside of it.